# Room missing compile-time SQL checks?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

In Google's tutorials I have the compile-time checking. In my own sandbox project I don't see them. It allows invalid invalid SQL passed into `@Query`.

See [Gist](https://gist.github.com/es0329/aa5638899f46157ddb425d60f2f68219) of what I think are the pertinent files.

Comment: whatis the problem with this `"SELECT * FROM person"`

Comment: As-presented, the query is valid. My issue is that I'm able to use invalid SQL without Android Studio raising a compile-time error, which is a primary feature of the Room persistence library.

Also, whoever voted "close," what's wrong with my inquiry?

Comment: i thing you should also add the `Room.databaseBuilder`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include code that **actually fails**, rather than code that works ("As-presented, the query is valid").

Comment: Ok, Gist updated with an invalid query.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the code generated by Room for this DAO and see what it did with your query. I don't think Room will catch all types of invalid SQL (e.g., malformed `WHERE` clause), but I would expect it to complain if you refer to columns that are not recognized, for example. You might also consider filing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using alpha release version of Room. If so, try changing to a stable release version.

I faced similar issue when using an alpha release version of Room. I used version `2.5.0-alpha01` and it didn't check queries at compile time. I tried changing the version to latest stable release version `2.4.2` and it fixed the issue. Hopefully this helps.